# Jenkins JUnit Plugin reports a build as unstable even if test fails

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

So I am using the Jenknis JUnit parser plugin to parse the test results. I have a job which has just one test and it fails all the time. However, the JUnit plugin marks the job as unstable and not failed.

Any reasons why?

I have tried to set the Health report amplification factor to 1, 0.1, 0.0 but no luck. Seems like somehow this is the reason why my job is reported as Unstable and not Failed.

How can I get the JUnit to fail the build?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find any solutions. I'm running on same issue that i don't want to build be marked as unstable when some test fail.

Comment: @Juge I havent found any solutions so far.

Comment: you can add a if statement after junit line in pseudocode  if (buildResult == 'UNSTABLE'){build.result=="FAIL"}

Answer (score 9):

The following workaround worked for me:

```
sh "test ${currentBuild.currentResult} != UNSTABLE"
```

I added this right after the junit step. So in the end your pipeline looks similar to this:

```
stage('test') {
    steps {
        sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -DtestFailureIgnore=true test"
    }
    post {
       success {
           junit '**/target/surefire-reports/**/*.xml'
           sh "test ${currentBuild.currentResult} != UNSTABLE"
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately JUnit reporter doesn't support failing the build. This is quite frustrating, because that's kind of a popular use case...

In any case, you need to implement a workaround. So you either:

1. Run the unit tests with allowing the test tool to fail the build (just let it throw it's non-0 exit code)
   or...
2. Save the exit code(s) of the test tool(s) and fail the build later. You can do that for any type of job (incl. Pipeline). For usual job then the `Execute shell` step would look smth like this:

   ```
   set +e                      # Disable the option to fail the job when any command fails
   phpunit                     # Run the tests
   unit_tests_exit_code=$?     # Save the exit code of the last command
   set -e                      # Re-enable the option to fail the job when any command fails

   echo "yolo"                 # Execute everything you want to run before you fail the job

   exit $unit_tests_exit_code  # You fail the job (if test run failed and phpunit returned a non-zero exit code)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In case the tests are run in a container and one wants to get the status of the tests from the exit code on the container, use these commands:

```bash
test_status=$(docker inspect <containerName/ID> --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}')
exit $test_status
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the option `skipStagesAfterUnstable`,
and then change the build status in a post hook.

```
pipeline {
  agent {}
  option {
    skipStagesAfterUnstable()
  }
  stages {
    // the stages...
  }
  post {
    always {
      script {
        // [Optional] Change build status to failure.
        if (currentBuild.currentResult == 'UNSTABLE') {
            currentBuild.result = "ERROR"
            sh 'echo "Unstable build, exiting now..."'
        }
        emailext(...)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options